# Passing List of Variables In Bash To External Program

Tags: linux, bash, unix, ubuntu

Good Afternoon Everyone,

This is probably a no-brainer but, I'm currently having issues passing a variable to a program in my bash script.

Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
regions=ne,se,vt,ma,sw,nw and so on and so forth
```

After that variable has been defined in my bash script, I'd then like to pass that variable into GrADS, where my script will read each of the regions one after the other until it reaches the end.

Comment: What is GrADS?  What input does it expect?

Comment: @Aaron Perry what is GrADS ?

Comment: GrADS is a Linux program that can be used to display nwp data. http://www.iges.org/grads/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most reliable means of passing variables I've found is to generate a text file with the code (or just the string) you want to pass from within the code. Alternatively, you could call GrADS (?) from within whatever program is generating the variable, and pass "$regions" as an argument.